# ScrollView is not showing the first item

Tags: android, android-scrollview

i have a scrollview in my layout. And when i build the project i cant see the first item of scroll view(which id is "nameET"). Can you please help me? Here is my xml.

I tried to set top margin to my top element(which is first item of scrollview). And it didnt work all devices.

Also i tried to change all matarialedittext to native edittext. Thats still not working :/

Thanks,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#00000000"
android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
android:id="@+id/scrollView7">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/nameET"
        android:hint="Benim Adım"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        app:met_baseColor="#000000"
        app:met_primaryColor="#6c6c6c"
        app:met_errorColor="#ec0000"
        app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="textCapWords" />

    <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/surnameET"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:hint="Soyadım"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        app:met_baseColor="#000000"
        app:met_primaryColor="#6c6c6c"
        app:met_errorColor="#ec0000"
        app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="textCapWords" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Cinsiyet:"
            android:id="@+id/genderTitle"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/maleLL">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="18dp"
                android:layout_height="18dp"
                android:id="@+id/maleGenderIV"
                android:src="@drawable/gender_unselected"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Erkek"
                android:id="@+id/maleTV"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/femaleLL">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="18dp"
                android:layout_height="18dp"
                android:id="@+id/femaleGenderIV"
                android:src="@drawable/gender_unselected"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Kadın"
                android:id="@+id/femaleTV"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Doğum Tarihi:"
            android:id="@+id/birthdayTitle"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/variant_border_gray"
            android:id="@+id/birthdayFL">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:id="@+id/birthdayTV"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView50"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/down_arrow" />
        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/passwordET"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:hint="Şifrem"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            app:met_baseColor="#000000"
            app:met_primaryColor="#6c6c6c"
            app:met_errorColor="#ec0000"
            app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/showPasswordIV"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
            android:src="@drawable/showpassword_icon"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/rePasswordET"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:hint="Şifrenizi Tekrarlayın"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            app:met_baseColor="#000000"
            app:met_primaryColor="#6c6c6c"
            app:met_errorColor="#ec0000"
            app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/showPasswordIV2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:src="@drawable/showpassword_icon"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dp" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/emailET"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:hint="Eposta Adresim"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        app:met_baseColor="#000000"
        app:met_primaryColor="#6c6c6c"
        app:met_errorColor="#ec0000"
        app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/phoneET"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:hint="Telefonum"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        app:met_baseColor="#000000"
        app:met_primaryColor="#6c6c6c"
        app:met_errorColor="#ec0000"
        app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:text="5__) _______" />

    <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/vakkoCardET"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:hint="Vakko Kart No"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        app:met_baseColor="#000000"
        app:met_primaryColor="#6c6c6c"
        app:met_errorColor="#ec0000"
        app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Vakko kartınızı ekleyebilmek için \nlütfen telefon numaranızı giriniz"
        android:id="@+id/vakkoCardTitle"
        android:textColor="#B3B3B3"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/termsofUseLL"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/termsofUseIV"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/checkbox_selection" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Üyelik koşullarını kabul ediyorum"
            android:id="@+id/termsofUseTV"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="#B3B3B3"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:id="@+id/announcementLL"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/announcementIV"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/checkbox_selection" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Vakko&apos;dan duyuruları almak istiyorum"
            android:id="@+id/announcementTV"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="#B3B3B3"
            android:textIsSelectable="false" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="ÜYE OL"
        android:id="@+id/registerTV"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="#3A3A3A"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Remove android:layout_gravity="center" in very first Linear layout(child) next to Scrollview .

Did the trick. It's showing complete layout in my emulator.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change nameET's `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`. Also, I don't think I can see a closing tag for your `ScrollView`

Comment: i changed to "wrap_content" and still not working :(

Comment: just for a test, Use a button widget as your first element and check if it is shown

Comment: i fixed my problem with remove "    android:layout_gravity="center" from first linearlayout. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:gravity="center_vertical"` instead of `android:layout_gravity="center"` in the first LinearLayout directly inside the ScrollView. I would also suggest that you use `NestedScrollView` as it is more compatible with most modern layouts like `CoordinatorLayout`

Answer (score 0):

in LinearLayout add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`
and use nestedScrollView